# Outlook Wait a few seconds then execute

Tags: vba, outlook

I have a simple VBA code in Outlook 2010 which prints any incoming emails automatically.

This script is set to run each time an email comes in through a rule.

Here is the code:

```
Sub printradu(Item As Outlook.MailItem)
       MessageAndAttachmentProcessor Item, True
End Sub
```

How can i make this script wait 10 seconds and then execute it. I need something like this:

```
Sub printradu(Item As Outlook.MailItem)
       'Wait 10 seconds then execute the code below:
       MessageAndAttachmentProcessor Item, True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try:

```
Sub printradu(Item As Outlook.MailItem)
    'Wait 10 seconds then execute the code below:
    Application.Wait(Now + TimeValue("0:00:10"))
    MessageAndAttachmentProcessor Item, True
End Sub
```

Or:

```
Public Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
Sub printradu(Item As Outlook.MailItem)
    'Wait 10 seconds then execute the code below:
    Sleep(10000)
    MessageAndAttachmentProcessor Item, True
End Sub
```

Or:

```
Sub printradu(Item As Outlook.MailItem)
    'Wait 10 seconds then execute the code below:
    Threading.thread.sleep(10000)
    MessageAndAttachmentProcessor Item, True
End Sub
```

Comment: Just a quick add-on question out of curiosity, do you know how can i make this happen before the Sub?

Comment: @RaduS, I don't know how to execute `sub`s with Rules. I believe you have to specify a `sub` to execute for that rule. In that case this is where you will land again ;)

Comment: What i meant is...is there any way i can insert the waiting time of 10 seconds before the sub starts? because now the waiting time is within the sub.

Comment: 1000 milliseconds is only 1 second ;)

Comment: @enderland, thanks for pointing it out. May be the first option worked for the asker so this was not pointed out ;) I have updated the answer :)

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me in Outlook 2013 VBA (for some reason I had to include "outlook." before the "Application.Wait"):

```
Outlook.Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:5"))
```